# how to replace backgrund url in css class using regexp (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an html string in which I want to replace url of background-image. But wasn't able to do it.

This code looks like html but actually its a string which have html data.

MY string

```
var html ="
.reg-inner {
background-image: linear-gradient),url(http:\\abc.com);
}

  .reg-left {
            background-image: linear-gradient),url(http:\\abc.com);
            background-size: cover;           
            }
.reg-right {
background-image: linear-gradient),url(http:\\abc.com);
}"
```

I want to replace the url after the .reg-left.

I applied this regex but it will replace first one.

```
html.replace(/url\((['"]?)(.+?)\1\)/, "url(" + replacableImage + ")");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML string is not HTML. It is CSS.

[Your regex works](https://regex101.com/r/20N3bV/1). You need to add a g to get all of them

Also you cannot have newlines in a JS string - you need backticks to allow the linefeeds

```js
const replacableImage = "abc.jpg";
let CSS =`
.reg-inner {
background-image: linear-gradient),url(http:\\abc.com);
}

  .reg-left {
            background-image: linear-gradient),url(http:\\abc.com);
            background-size: cover;           
            }
.reg-right {
background-image: linear-gradient),url(http:\\abc.com);
}`
CSS = CSS.replace(/url\((['"]?)(.+?)\1\)/g, "url(" + replacableImage + ")")
console.log(CSS)
```

If you only want one of them, you can run a replace function or a split+map+join

```js
const replacableImage = "abc.jpg";
let CSS = `
.reg-inner {
background-image: linear-gradient),url(http:\\abc.com);
}

  .reg-left {
            background-image: linear-gradient),url(http:\\abc.com);
            background-size: cover;           
            }
.reg-right {
background-image: linear-gradient),url(http:\\abc.com);
}`

CSS = CSS.split('.reg-').map(
    str => str.indexOf('left') === 0 ?
    str.replace(/url\((['"]?)(.+?)\1\)/, `url("${replacableImage}")`) : str
  )
  .join('.reg-')

console.log(CSS)
```

Comment: thanks for response, but if i add g in expression then it will replace all urls but i want to replace specific url which comes after .reg-left. @mplungjan

Comment: how can we check only after the reg-left , url should be replaced in regex ?